# How to copy everything from a Database . Pl Sql

Tags: database, oracle, copy, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am on SQL developer and I want to copy everything(I mean and the data) from one database to another. I tried with -->Tools-->Database Copy . But it copied only the structure without the data. Can someone help me.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the check box **Copy Data**. If you select only **Copy DDL**, it won't copy the data.

[image]

You could see the demonstration step by step here http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r31/DatabaseCopy/DatabaseCopy.html

Comment: When I go to Database Copy at the left of the window I have only   Source / Destination and Copy Summary. There is no Object Types, Select Tablespace, Specify Objects, specify Data and Copy Summary. So the only thing I do is to choose source connection and Destination Connection and press Next and then Finish at the copy summary

Comment: and at the Source/Destination page I have only source and destination option and below this to choose between 3 options Create Objects , Truncate Objects, Drop Objects.

Comment: Is there any case I am needing the Database Export and not the Copy?

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using? Perhaps, if the feature is not available, then you could do export/import of full database.

Comment: I am so noob my friend.. from where can I see which version I have?? And also can you tell me.. how to do the export/import thing? (I am scared because I dont want to ruin anything in the companys' database :/ )

Comment: To check the version, go to `Help --> About`

Comment: my version is 2.1.1.64 . I did the export.. now I need to do the import .. how I do it.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
After I created a directory with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR AS '/usr/bin/bfile_dir';
```

I used this at the command prompt to do the export:

```
expdp BASE/BASE@MPORA11G schemas=BASE full=Y directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR
```

After this.. to import the exported db in my new base BASELOCAL I used at the cmd :

```
impdp BASELOCAL/BASELOCAL@ORCL full=yes directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR
```

Comment: Good that you have learned to do it from command line rather than depending on a tool. By the way, from 10g and up, you don't have to create a directory for `DATA_PUMP_DIR`, it is a **default directory**. You just need to place the files there and use parameter directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR. Good luck!